# for loops for ceaser cypher calculator

Tags: c++

I'm trying to check a string against a word list with a for loop the wordlist is 100 words long but I don't think I'm using the find right. it always said that it found a word when it had only shifted by one and had clearly not found a word. your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
string Alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnogqrstuvwxyz";

cout << "Enter your string > " << flush;

getline(cin, OldString);

int Length = OldString.length();

for (int k = 0; k <= 25; k++) {

for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++) {

    //cout << i << endl;

    if(OldString[i] == Alphabet[26]){

        NewString = NewString + Alphabet[26] ;
    }
        else {
        Result = Alphabet.find(OldString[i], 0);

        //cout << Result << endl;

        NewString = NewString + Alphabet[Result + 1];
    }

}

for (int x = 0; x < 99; x++) {

    int WordCheck = NewString.find(WordList[x], 0);

if (WordCheck >= 0) {

    cout << NewString << endl;
    cout << "/n is this in english. 1 = yes. 2 = no." << endl;

    cin >> YN;

    if (YN == 1) {
        cout << "code broken" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }


}
```

Comment: `int WordCheck = NewString.find(WordList[x], 0);` will look for substring, you probably want `bool WordCheck = NewString == WordList[x];`. if you keep `std::string::find`, use std::size_t as result and check with `std::string::npos`, not positive result.

Comment: Notice also that you transform `'z'` into `' '` instead of `'a'`

Comment: thanks for the feedback but I'm still not very good at programming and don't understand what I should do to fix my code.